# How to convert ARIMA forecast output to Date

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I have got the output from the ARIMA forecast. But I don't know how to convert the first column to date. The output is the prediction for the last days of 2021 and I wanted to get the date or a day number of 2021. Is it possible?

Following is the first column output which I need to convert:

2021.9589   is the output for 17th Dec.
2021.9616   is the output for 18th Dec.
2021.9644   is the output for 19th Dec.
2021.9671       ... and so on....
2021.9699
2021.9726
2021.9753
2021.9781
2021.9808
2021.9836
2021.9863
2021.989
2021.9918
2021.9945
2021.9973
2022.0000
2022.0027
2022.0055

Answer (score 2):

I would use `date_decimal`, from `lubridate`, it works like:

```
> require(lubridate)
( d <- date_decimal(2021.9589) )
[1] "2021-12-16 23:57:50 UTC"
```

And then use `month` and `day` functions:

```
> month(d)
[1] 12
> day(d)
[1] 16
```